# Unable to delete a row using MySQL triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a trigger in MySQL

```
 DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER trigger2
BEFORE INSERT ON participated FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN    
 IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM participated WHERE driver_id = NEW.driver_id) > 3) THEN 
     DELETE FROM accident WHERE report_no = NEW.report_no;         
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = "Driver is already involved in 3 accciddents"; 
END IF; 
END;$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

First an accident report is inserted into accident table. Before inserting in to participated table if it involves a driver who has participated in more than 3 accident a waring has to be given and driver's data in accident table should be deleted.

```
'accident' and 'participated' are the two tables.

 accident(report_no,date,location);
  participated(driver_id,reg_no,report_no,amount);
```

ex:

```
 insert into accident values(34,"2022-04-05","bangalore");

 insert into participated values("D1","KA-09-MM-5644",34,20000);

 ERROR 1644 (45000): Driver is already involved in 3 accciddents
```

Warning is working but it is not deleting the row in accident table. accident table still has the row with `report_no 34`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body part in Mysql trigger is like a single ALL-OR-NOTHING transaction. This means every query inside has to be successful, or the entire process is undone. By using `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text` , an error is intentionally raised, which rolls back every thing that has happend so far, and a message is returned. Note, the INSERT statement itself is cancelled due to error induced. Of course, it's possible to ignore the error by declaring a continue handler in the very begining of the trigger.

```
BEGIN
declare continue handler for SQLSTATE '45000' begin end;    
 IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM participated WHERE driver_id = NEW.driver_id) > 3) THEN 
     DELETE FROM accident WHERE report_no = NEW.report_no;         
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = "Driver is already involved in 3 accciddents"; 
END IF; 
END
```

This will make sure things keep going after SQLSTATE '45000' is encountered. However, the message_text is **IGNORED**, as it's only intended to show up to address a warning/error, not for a continue handler. And regrettably, we can not return a result set using a trigger. So if we add a SELECT statement or something alike after the SIGNAL statement , an error will pop up:

```
select "Driver is already involved in 3 accciddents" as a warning; 
-- OR
show warnings;
-- Error Code: 1415. Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger
```

If we really need a message to show up,we can considering using a procedure to bypass the restriction enforced by trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER trigger2
BEFORE INSERT ON participated FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN    
 IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM participated WHERE driver_id = NEW.driver_id) > 3) THEN 
     DELETE FROM accident WHERE report_no = NEW.report_no;         
SET @warning = "Driver is already involved in 3 accciddents"; -- here we don't really need a SIGNAL statement. Just creating a user variable is adequate.
else set @warning=null;
END IF; 
END$$

create procedure insert_participated (d_id varchar(20),rg_no varchar(20),rp_no int,amt int)
begin
insert into participated values(d_id,rg_no,rp_no,amt);
if @warning is not null then 
select @warning as warning;
end if;
end $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

By using a procedure ,we can display a message. And if we directly use an insert statement(when we forget to use the procedure), the trigger's operation still applies. Therefore, we might think about adding an INSERT statement to populate an auditing table for future reference.

Comment: You said by using `signal sqlstate...` everything done so far is reverted back. So it is better to apply the trigger to `accident` table itself right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `accident` table. When we use `signal` statement, we want to abort the trigger process immediately and make sure nothing changes. In your case, I suppose you focus more on displaying the message rather than using `signal` to force an abortion. As in your previous IF statement, a condition check is already in set to guarantee the execution logic. You don't need the `SIGNAL` statement to simulate an error. You just want a message to show up while the trigger runs smoothly.

Comment: However, this is not intended for the use of trigger, which does not allow return of a result set such as a message. The exception is using `SIGNAL` to force an error/warning, which terminates the trigger, and returns a message (of your choice)  to server as a warning notice for you. And if a continue handler is declared beforehand to adress a problem which either happend naturally or intentionally by using `signal`, the trigger keeps going and no message is returned.

Comment: To put it in a nutshell, trigger is not supposed to return something back to your console unless something went amiss. That's why I suggest using a stored procedure as a workaround if you really care about returning a message, as well as using the trigger to record the action in an auditing table for future reference.